# How to setup margin responsively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to setup a div with bootstrap.

My problem is that I need to have a set margin on the left and right of the div. By using col-md-10 doesn't get me the margin I need. It's more than 10px if the screen is wide.

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
    //contents...
</div>

 -------------------------------------
|  ---------    div   --------------
|10px margin              10px margin
|  |                               |
|  |                               |
|   -------------------------------
 -------------------------------------
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems to me that you need to include the class for another sizes, for example: xs, sm, and lg.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you can get rid of the classes, the float, the width and just set `margin: 0 10px;` on the div it defaults to be responsive automatically... why even use the default bootstrap css if you're changing all the default styles on the div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want always a `margin` value of 10px at each side. You can create a custom class and use `calc()`, try this:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 margin">
    //contents...
</div>

.margin {
   margin:0 10px;
   width:calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Check this **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/jirKhQOkvE)**

---

Another Option could be a custom class on the container and use `padding`. Try:

```
<div class="container margin">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        //contents...
    </div>
</div>

.margin {
  width:100%;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

Another **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/4RN2OqHRP5)**

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `container-fluid` class on your main content div.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Contents --> 
</div>
```

What this does is creates a full-width container with a bit of padding on the right and left, top and bottom that responsively resizes based on the width of your browser.

Hope this helps!