# How to setup the margin in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to setup a responsive design for my divs and I also want to maintain the left and the right margin to 5px no matter the screen width. The problem I have is I have 5 div inside a parent div and I am not sure how to set the grid.

My previous pose for the similar question. It's not taking account of child divs.
[How to setup margin responsively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386964/how-to-setup-margin-responsively)

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            //contents...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            //contents...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            //contents...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            //contents...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            //contents...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will produce:

```
 -------------------------------------
|5px+ ----  ----  ----  ----  ---- 5px+
|      div    div   div  div   div 
|
|
|
```

I am not sure how to maintain the 5px for every screen. Can anyone help me about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I post on the other answer you can use custom class definitions. In this case if the number of `col` doesn't fit the request of `12` you can do this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row margin">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            //contents...
        </div>
        ..........
    </div>
</div>

.margin {
  padding:0 5px;
  }
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .margin > div {
    background:red;
    width:20%;
  }
}
```

Check this **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/124FNTFuBZ)**

Answer (score 0):

You will give yourself a headache if you use margins on grids. Switch to padding and it won't affect the grid:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Padding can be added to any column without having to worry about it breaking.